# Multiple vararg-parameters are prohibited

Tags: android, kotlin

In my Android project:

I need to pass multiple vararg params like this:

```
fun createTransportResponse(response: Response<*>, vararg throwableArrays: Throwable, vararg errorResponsePair: Pair<Int, String>): TransportResponse {
            val transportResponse = TransportResponse()
}
```

But on second vararg param I had compile error:

```
Multiple vararg-parameters are prohibited
```

Comment: The error message says plainly that you cannot have multiple varargs parameters in the same function, so what are you actually asking?

Comment: @Alexei then pass two lists instead?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Kotlin Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html)

> Only one parameter may be marked as vararg. If a vararg parameter is not the last one in the list, values for the following parameters can be passed using the named argument syntax, or, if the parameter has a function type, by passing a lambda outside parentheses.

As the compiler tells you already, it is not possible to have multiple vararg parameters. You should consider passing the values wrapped in a `List`, an `Array`or a similar data strucutre.